# Fiddler 2.5.1.0 is not exporting captured traffic to visual studio file

Tags: asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I'm using Fiddler 2.5.1.0 version to capture traffic to our asp.net web api restful services. when I just select part of the entire traffic (like a selected session) and go to File-> Export Sessions -> Selected Session, a little dialog box pops up with a drop down menu on it . I select Visual Studio Web Test click next and saves the selected session as .webtest file.

But when I open that saved .webtest file all I get is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TestCase Name="FiddlerGeneratedWebTest" Id="" Owner="" Description=""    Priority="0" Enabled="True" CssProjectStructure="" CssIteration=""    DeploymentItemsEditable="" CredentialUserName="" CredentialPassword=""   PreAuthenticate="True" Proxy="" RequestCallbackClass=""   TestCaseCallbackClass="">
  <Items />
  </TestCase>
```

Where are all the Urls that I was able to capture with Fiddler? I need this file in order to run a Load Test in Visual studio.

I tried visual studio's web performance test but after a certain point it doesn't seem to capture the traffic, though in IE when I try to get the data from the database through our Web API I can successfully go through the entire asp.net web api pipeline (request and response) see the data getting displayed on the client side in IE. As I said web test recording stops capturing the URLS in the left side pane of IE after a certain point, but that's what essentially I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this trick that we need to do, once export for the selected session is done and .webtest file is saved on the local disk. A dialog box pops up just uncheck the plug-ins there and one will be able to see the .webtest xml file populated with all the urls for the selected session.

Comment: Yes, the plugins are designed to remove certain kinds of requests, as described by the name of each plugin. You should untick the plugins that you do not wish to use.